# Display vertical histogram java

Tags: java

I need help to display my stars vertically. But I don't know how to. I managed to display the star but its not neat. If you have any other ways to do this, please display your answer.

This is my variable:

```
    int Count = 0; //total number of marks entered 
    int catOne = 0; //counters for each catergory
    int cat2 = 0;   //counters for each catergory
    int cat3 = 0;  //counters for each catergory
    int cat4 = 0; //counters for each catergory
    int mark = 0;
    int totalPassed = 0; //entered by user
    double averageScore = 0;
    int lowMark = 102;
    int highMark = 0;
    int mark1 = 0;
    int value = 0;
    boolean run = false;
```

This is my code for vertical stars:

```
    //Vertical
    System.out.println("0-29  30-39  40-69  70-100");
    for (int i = 0; i < catOne; i++) {
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.print("");
        System.out.print("*        ");//display the amount of students recieved the mark


    }
     System.out.print("");
    for (int i = 0; i < cat2; i++) {
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.print("");
        System.out.print("        *"); //display the amount of students recieved the mark

    }
     System.out.print("");
    for (int i = 0; i < cat3; i++) {
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.print("");
        System.out.print("              *");//display the amount of students recieved the mark
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cat4; i++){ 
        System.out.println("  "); 
        System.out.print("");
        System.out.print("                        *"); //display the amount of students recieved the mark
        System.out.print("");
    }
```

The output of this code is this:

```
0-29  30-39  40-69  70-100

*          
*  
*        
        *  
              *  
                        *  
                        *  
                        *
```

Comment: check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array instead of separate variables for loops. That makes it far more easier. Since the amount of stars may vary in each category, check the maximum number of stars, which denotes the boundary for an outer loop to print lines. An inner loop creates each line by iterating your `categories` array. Here is the code:

```
int[] categories = new int[4];

// ...set the values for the categories directly...
// ...or copy them like this:
// categories[0] = catOne; 
// categories[1] = cat2; 
// categories[2] = cat3;
// categories[3] = cat4;

int maximum = 0;
for (int value : categories) {
    if(value > maximum) {
        maximum = value;
    }
}

// The above loop is the short version of:
// for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
//     if (categories[i] > maximum) {
//         maximum = categories[i];
//     }
// }

// Added "00", so the colums have equal width
System.out.println("00-29  30-39  40-69  70-100\n");

for (int i = 0; i < maximum; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        if (categories[j] > i) {
            System.out.print("*      ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("       ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Many thank, for your answer. My application is for the user to display the values, I cant provide values.  furthermore there is an error with this             for    (int value : categories) {                               - *it says variable value is already defined in method string

Comment: I checked the code, no errors raised and the output is what you wanted. What do you mean by "I cant provide values"?

Comment: is it possible to display vertical histogram without an array, if you can you show me the code please

Comment: That would be very verbose and repetitious. I have added further comments, so you can just copy your values. Better take this as an example to read up on the concepts you do not understand completely, it is worth it.

Comment: thank you very much. editing your comment made everything clear for me. It finally worked. Your help, helped me to pass my semester.